# RCP extensions from several plugin's

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have RCP, and 2 products, based on fetures. I have my.project.gui plugin, that have some gui-extensios, like views, perspectives, prefetencePages. etc..

First product have some gui (feature of this product includes my.project.gui). And I want to my second product to have some extended gui. I created plugin, named my.project.gui.extended and added it to my second project feature. Then added some gui-excensions to my.project.gui.extended. But this doest work! I lauch my second product and see only my.project.gui-extensions, and dont see my.project.gui.extended-extensions.

Tried to add my.project.gui.extended to all dependences, but this didnt solve problem.

Is there any things i need to do to make this work? Or I need to this job in some other way?

===================================

Added information:

```
1st product feature has:
my.product.main1 (plugin with 1st product, application class, etc... has gui in dependences),
my.product.gui,
my.product.shared,
my.product.others1

2nd product feature has:
my.product.main2 (plugin with 2nd product, application class, etc... has gui and gui.extended in dependences),
my.product.gui,
my.product.gui.extended,
my.product.shared,
my.product.others2
```

type of extention is org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages (2nd product has server preference page, but 1st doesn't)

i think this is not runtime problem.

Comment: You must describe this in a lot more details.. How are your features defined? And the products? Dependencies between the plug-ins? Which extensions are we talking about? etc, etc

Comment: The type of extension are important.  For example, if you updated something that effects a perspective but you already had it open in your runtime, you wouldn't see the change take effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by adding this extensions to my.product.main2, not to my.product.gui.extended. This is not exectly what i wanted, but it works